# JSF localization and pluralization using message-bundles

Tags: jsf, localization, messageformat

I'm using a message bundle, to localize the output of my application. Now I want to add pluralization and I wonder if there's a way to achieve that by using the message properties files along with message parameters?

Something like that:

```
<h:outputFormat value="#{msg['label.bean']}">
    <f:param value="#{someBean.someProp.size()}" />
</h:outputFormat>
```

to result in:

> 0 beans, 1 bean, 2 beans, ...

The format `label.bean={0} bean` works for the count of course, but how do I get the plural "s" depending on the value of `{0}`?

Answer (score 2):

The [`<h:outputFormat>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/outputFormat.html) uses [`MessageFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) under the covers. According to its javadoc, you can use [`ChoiceFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/ChoiceFormat.html) for this. Further usage is in detail explained in its javadoc.

In your case, the following message format pattern should do it:

```
label.bean = {0} bean{0,choice,0#s|1#|1<s}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this

```
<ui:param name="plu" value="#{(someBean.someProp.size() eq 1)?'single_key':'multi_key'}"/>

<h:outputFormat value="#{msg[plu]}">
    <f:param value="#{someBean.someProp.size()}" />
</h:outputFormat>
```

where the labels look like this

```
single_key= {0} bean

multi_key= {0} beans
```

Comment: Yes, that's what i'm doing at the moment. Was just wondering, if there is NO better way to achieve that. something like calling
#msg[key, param] and defining key=(param==1)?singular:plural